# How to use GEOGRAPHY functions in Bigquery to convert Canadian FSA shapefiles?

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, geopandas, looker-studio

I am trying to use bigquery and google data studio to create an interactive filled map but I am struggling to get bigquery to convert the geometry into the correct geography type required by bigquery and data studio. The goal is an output that looks like something like the maps provided on this link: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10502383?hl=en

The shapefile that I am trying to work with is: [Statscan FSA Boundary Shapefile](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lfsa000b16a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2044221&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lfsa000b16a_e.zip) and the error that I am getting is: "ST_GeogFrom failed: Latitude must be between -90 and 90 degrees. Actual value was 2149529.03143"

I'm not sure if there is some sort of conversion that needs to be done in terms of the CRS or how to resolve this issue.

I've tried this [medium article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-load-geographic-data-like-zipcode-boundaries-into-bigquery-25e4be4391c8) and am still running into issues. Any advice or suggestions on what I could try would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this article, it uses same org2org, but adds transform to lng:lat coordinate space with spatial SQL's `ST_Transform` call:

https://mentin.medium.com/loading-large-spatial-features-to-bigquery-geography-2f6ceb6796df

```
ogr2ogr -f csv -dialect sqlite -sql
"select AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geometry, 4326)) geom, * from shp" 
out.csv ./input/
```

Comment: This helped with the errors but it seems like the polygons are broken/aren't all converted properly. Not sure what the best way to fix this is and probably is more related to GIS then bigquery

Comment: Explain "broken"

Comment: When using the ST_GeogFromGeoJSON function in bigquery, I  would get the following error: ST_GeogFromGeoJSON failed: Invalid polygon loop: Edge 0 has duplicate vertex with edge 616. I tried to bypass this by using the parameter `make_valid => True` but when trying to plot the polygons in google data studio the majority of the polygons were missing and fragmented (not connecting).